# phpdocx + ob_clean + download = error

Tags: php, phpdocx

I use `phpdocx` library to make reports in Word. By default, `download` function contains these lines:

```
$this->save($tmp_filename);
... many headers
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($tmp_filename);            
exit;
```

With `ob_clean` function nothing happens - nothing is loaded. If I comment out this line, then the file starts to load. But it gets loaded with an error, which appears when I try to open the file. The error message says that the file is corrupt etc. However, if I open the temporary file itself - it is ok. So, what I want to know is what can be wrong with `ob_clean` function and with the download function on the whole.

**EDIT**

I replaced `ob_clean` with `ob_end_clean` and the problem has gone away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use ob clean or flush; there is a built in function that does that for phpdocx:

For example:

```
require_once '../../classes/CreateDocx.inc';
$docx = new CreateDocx();
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.';
$docx->addText($text, $paramsText);
$docx->createDocxAndDownload('example_text');
```

@ref: http://www.phpdocx.com/api-documentation/layout-and-general/create-and-download-docx-with-PHP

Comment: It seems as if my library (I mean phpdocx) got outdated. When I first incorporated it into my app, it contained just a couple of files. So, there is no `createDocxAndDownload` in my sourcecode now

Comment: have you looked into http://phpword.codeplex.com/? i use it for my word generation in apps that require automated word .docx generation. codeplex also has phpexcel which is also use. the documentation for it great with ton of sample code snippets. i used composer to install the source for my app library which is upto date if it ever got outdated. in addition, its open source and its free. i think phpdocx is paid licensed issue. I had challenges when I tried to create .doc file instead I used the open source standard .docx which are bunch of xml notations.

Comment: in office 2003 and below there is a comp package you can download from MS website to support .docx files.